# Get more strings values in one dialog?

Tags: dialog, dm-script

how to get more (at least>5) strings values in one dialog? 
like below, I can get the string value of str1

```
string str1
GetString("studentID", " ", str1)
```

If there are 6 strings, is there a way I can get the values of all 6 strings in one dialog?

Answer (score 0):

The basic script commands for premade dialogs only support the simplest use-cases. For any type of dialog which does more, you have to create your own dialog class and object.

This isn't so hard, though. Please refer to the F1 help section on dialogs here:

[image: F1 help on dialogs]

In fact, your exact question is covered in the example section of the F1 help here:

[image: Help examples]

Based on this example, a method that gives a 6-string dialog would look f.e. like:

```
number GetSixStringsDialog( string &str1, string &str2, string &str3, string &str4, string &str5, string &str6 )
{
    TagGroup DLG, DLGItems
    DLG = DLGCreateDialog( "Please enter strings", DLGItems )
    TagGroup val1tg, val2tg, val3tg, val4tg, val5tg, val6tg
    DLGitems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateStringField( "1st: ", val1tg, str1, 30 ) )
    DLGitems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateStringField( "2nd: ", val2tg, str2, 30 ) )
    DLGitems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateStringField( "3rd: ", val3tg, str3, 30 ) )
    DLGitems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateStringField( "4th: ", val4tg, str4, 30 ) )
    DLGitems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateStringField( "5th: ", val5tg, str5, 30 ) )
    DLGitems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateStringField( "6th: ", val6tg, str6, 30 ) )

    number result = Alloc( UIframe ).Init( DLG ).Pose() 
    str1 = val1tg.DLGGetStringValue()
    str2 = val2tg.DLGGetStringValue()
    str3 = val3tg.DLGGetStringValue()
    str4 = val4tg.DLGGetStringValue()
    str5 = val5tg.DLGGetStringValue()
    str6 = val6tg.DLGGetStringValue()

    return result
 }

string s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6
s1 = "PreText 1"
s4 = "PreText 4"
if ( !GetSixStringsDialog( s1, s2, s3, s4 ,s5, s6 ) )
    Throw( "User cancel" )

Result( "\n Entered strings are:" )
Result( "\n1:" + s1 )
Result( "\n2:" + s2 )
Result( "\n3:" + s3 )
Result( "\n4:" + s4 )
Result( "\n5:" + s5 )
Result( "\n6:" + s6 )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, is there any code/command can let these 6 dialogs remember the content that were input in last time until we input new content? Thanks again

Comment: You need to provide this yourself in your script. You need to store the returned values and then feed them back in the next time as pre-value just as done in the example with s1 or s4

Comment: so there is a code to store the string value, after the scripting was closed, the string still remember  the value in last script running?

Comment: @together If you want to store data outside the runtime of a single script, you have to store it 'somewhere'. Usually, this is done as a tagGroup object. You can store tagGroups either in the "persistentTags or globalTags" (the preference file), with any open image ("image tags") or by storing it to disc as a file (.gtg file). For the dialog, you most likely want to use the global tags. If any of this is not clear to you, please ask it as a separate question.